# FireBreath does not compile with boost process header file included

Tags: firebreath

I wanted to launch the process from firebreath,so I included "boost/process.hpp". Just including this header alone throws compile error.
could some one help?

FireBreath 1.6.1, FireBreath 1.7.0,windows 8

Error:

2>C:\Projects\plugin\FireBreath\src\3rdParty\boost\boost/process/detail/pipe.hpp(129): error C2665: 'boost::system::system_error::system_error' : none of the 7 overloads could convert all the argument types
2> C:\Projects\plugin\FireBreath\src\3rdParty\boost\boost/system/system_error.hpp(39): could be 'boost::system::system_error::system_error(int,const boost::system::error_category &,const std::string &)'
2> C:\Projects\plugin\FireBreath\src\3rdParty\boost\boost/system/system_error.hpp(43): or 'boost::system::system_error::system_error(int,const boost::system::error_category &,const char *)'
2> while trying to match the argument list '(DWORD, overloaded-function, const char [54])'

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem

```
boost: 1.47
OS:    Windows XP (32 bit VM)
```

But not with FireBreath

I changed `boost::system::system_category` to `boost::system::system_category()` in pipe.hpp line 129

Answer (score 1):

the boost::process library that was in FireBreath has compilation errors in them.  I have fixed those errors and it now compiles for me, at least when including .  I  haven't actually tried to use it on windows yet, nor I suspect has anyone else.

Good luck, hope that helps.